# jQuery effects disappears on reload

Tags: jquery, reload

Im hiding a few elements on my website with jQuery, but the effect disappears when reload the page. How I can store jQuery and avoid that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sf-label-radio').text('');
    $('.sf-item-0').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Consider using session storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 0):

You can either use cookies or local storage.

Cookies:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

To set value in a cookie:

```
  $.cookie("anyname", 1);
```

To read back the value of the cookie:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("anyname");
```

For Local Storage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I can't get it. How I can set $('.sf-item-0').css('display', 'none'); to cookie for example?

Comment: You can set $.cookie("sf-item-0", 'hide'); Then on load you can read this value  var cookieValue = $.cookie("sf-item-0"); And based on that value you can hide or show.